# how can i make these string '1\u202f327' "1\u202f489" usable?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, beautifulsoup, data-science

there is this data i want to **scrape** for a school project from this google link
https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=morts+corona+par+wilaya&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8.
evrything is fine i could get all the data i wanted, however i have a small problem which i can't solve.

my problem is this, i saved the data of the table in a list of list, so i have noticed that when i print evrything the first two elements do not print properly
[["Wilaya d'Alger", **'1\u202f327'**, '261', '145'], ['Wilaya de Blida', **'1\u202f489',** '133', '131'], ...]]
however but when i print these specific values they get printed properly
**1 327**,
**1 489**

i have tried saving in a csv file, i have noticed that the values are well printed in the file but i still get errors due to the values mentioned above stating that this string cant not be converted to a number

**ValueError: could not convert string to float: '1\u202f302'**

Comment: Which list? Can you post a link to the website you are scraping off? I just get a list of Google Search results when I click your link?

Comment: What's going on there is that you have a narrow-no-break-space as thousands separator (the standard thousand separator in Europe) which is coded as `\u202f`. Just remove it before converting the number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\u202` is [Right-to-Left override character](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/202e/index.htm), which has representation as simple white space.

If you want to convert the string to float, you can do:

```
s = '1\u202f489'

print(float(s.replace('\u202f', '')))
```

Which prints:

```
1489.0
```

---

Or:

```
print(float(''.join(s.split())))
```

---

Or using `re`:

```
print(float(''.join(re.findall(r'\d+', s))))
```